# How is naturality used here?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm trying to understand why in order to prove the claim:

> For an invertible linear transformation $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ show that the induced map on $H_n(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\})\approx \tilde{H}_n(\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\})\approx\mathbb{Z}$ is $1$ or $-1$ according to whether the determinant of $f$ is positive or negative.

it follows **by naturality** that it suffices to prove the statement for:

$$f_*: H_{n-1}(\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\})\to H_{n-1}(\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\})$$

I'm familiar with the commutative diagrams in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology* on pag. 127-128 but I'm not sure how this one fits in to those diagrams. I'm assuming the following one is the one I should be using somehow (?)

[image]

Any advice would be much appreciated.

(the claim that naturality suffices is from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/806133/determining-the-induced-map-on-homology-tildeh-n-mathbbrn-0-of-f))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the determinant of $f$ is positive, then $f$ is in fact homotopic to the identity, and what you want is easy. Suppose then that that determinant ios negative, so that $f$ is homotopic to a reflection. We can therefore suppose that $f$ is the map $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\mapsto (-x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$.

This $f$ restricts to the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$, and naturality gives us a commutative diagram

```
H_{n-1}(S^{n-1}) —> H_{n-1}(R^n-0)
   |                  |
   V                  V
H_{n-1}(S^{n-1}) —> H_{n-1}(R^n-0)
```

with horizontal arrows induced by the inclusion — and isomorphisms — and the vertical arrows induced by $f$. It follows from this that the map induced by $f$ on $H_{n-1}(R^n-0)$ is $-1$ exactly when then map it induces on $H_{n-1}(S^{n-1})$ is $-1$. Now do something with degrees to compute the map indauced on $H_{n-1}(S^{n-1})$.

That is one place where naturality helps you.

Next, you want to compute the map induce by $f$ on $H_n(R^n,R^n-0)$, and naturality gives us a commutative diagram

```
H_n(R^n) —> H_n(R^n,R^n-0) —>  H_{n-1}(R^n-0) —> H_{n-1}(R^n)
   |               |               |              |
   V               V               V              V
H_n(R^n) —> H_n(R^n,R^n-0) —>  H_{n-1}(R^n-0) —> H_{n-1}(R^n)
```

with rows long exact sequences for the pair $(R^n,R^n-0)$ and vertical arrows induced by $f$. The four vertices of this diagram are zeros (I am secretly using reduced homology), so the commutativity gets you the map you want.

Comment: Great explanation - this really lifted a fog! Very helpful for my understanding of how to use naturality. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you consider the first diagram as one that follows by naturality? I though that naturality refers to commutativity when the horizontal maps are long exact sequences of pairs (as per Hatcher's descriptions). Is this term loosely used for general diagram commutativity too?

Comment: The top and bottom arrows of that square are part of long exact sequences in homology!